# Convert date when fill datepicker manually in Angular

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, momentjs, angular-directive

I'm using [`Persian DatePicker`](https://github.com/AminRahimi/angular-bootstrap-persian-datepicker) which is bulit from `datePicker AngularUi` to dispaly date in shamsi calendar.
that's ok but when i to add date manually , datepicker can't convert it properly .
I've searched a lot about this and see pepole use momentjs to parse date and i should create directive for that but i'm not able to do this with custom directive .

**so the problem is i can't manullay fill the date picker !!**

here is my plunker : [`**`**Demo**`**`](http://plnkr.co/edit/W15JnbkoLQqAS4CYqWQM?p=preview)

**Note** : there is a plugin for moment js called momentjalali that added to project , this plugin convert date into `shamsi/jalali date`